# How to sort bar charts synchronous with the ticks of x axis

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am adopting the example from Mike Bostock to sort bar charts - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705.

However, the transition of the bars and the ticks of the x axis are not occuring at the same time.
The reason is that the transition is called separately for the bars and the ticks (in the function change():

```
transition.selectAll(".bar")
    .delay(delay)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x0(d.letter); });

transition.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("g")
    .delay(delay);
```

The solution should be when constructing the svg, I would like to add each bar to the corresponding tick.
However I didn't succeed to correctly adjusting the line

```
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")...
```

e.g.

```
svg.selectAll("g.tick")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")...// would put all the bars under each g.tick
```

or

```
svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")...// would put the bars after all g.tick's at the end. So again I can't grap the whole group together later.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting idea.

You can get the `rects` grouped with each tick's `g` by:

```
svg.selectAll(".x>.tick")
  .data(data)
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return -x.rangeBand()/2; // set x to be half width, tick g will position it
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return -(height - y(d.frequency)); // set y to negative
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  });
```

You then have to rewrite the transition since calling `.call(xAxis);` will recreate the tick `g` and remove the bars.

```
transition.selectAll(".x>.tick")
  .delay(delay)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.letter) + ",0)";
  });
```

Putting this [together](http://plnkr.co/edit/8m4mRr5KykvY72KkgkmG?p=preview).

Comment: Bingo. That seems to be the right solution. Thanks so much, I will accept and upvote the answer later today when I have a chance to try it. Can you please just elaborate a bit why this css selector works (e.g.in comparison with my selectors) since all articles I read about the data joins explain the join not how to append the elements at different places in the DOM tree.

Comment: @ee2Dev, `g.tick` won't work, that'll return the y ticks as well.  `.x.axis` doesn't work since it returns the `g` containing the x ticks and not the ticks themselves.  Finally, `.bar` returns the rects, but you want the rects in the ticks, not the ticks in the rects (to take advantage of the d3's axis helper).  Finally, I found I need to drop the `.enter()` after my `.x>.tick` as the axis data is already bound to each tick and d3 would not re-enter after binding the rect data.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great and quick reply! The difference is not so visible in M Bostocks example but in my own code it really shows...I looked back what I did wrong. Actually, unlike I wrote above, I tried: svg.select(".x.axis").selectAll(".tick").selectAll(".bar").data(data).enter().append("rect").... following the typically enter,update pattern. But that created all bars for each tick! I have to think through your approach, I guess you just attach the data and append the bars knowing they match...

Comment: The reason any approach with ...selectAll(".bar").data(data).enter().ap‌​pend("rect")... does not work is that any enter() selection contains a group that stores the parent node. All elements form the enter() selections are then either append or inserted IN SUCCESSION after the parent node. So with the enter() selection it is not possible to distribute the elements in a non subsequent fashion.